# Firebase to ImageView - How come even when there is no image, my chat will display an image?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a standard chat display method for a Firebase chat:

```
private void displayChat() {

    final ListView listOfMessage = findViewById(R.id.list_of_message);
    final String DATABASE_URL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com";
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages").child(chatName).limitToLast(20);
    FirebaseListOptions<Message> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Message>()
            .setLayout(R.layout.list_item)
            .setQuery(query, Message.class)
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .build();

    FirebaseListAdapter<Message> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Message>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Message model, int position) {

            //Get reference to the views of list_item.xml
            TextView messageText, messageUser, messageTime;
            ImageView img;
            messageText = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            messageUser = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            messageTime = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
            img = v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            if (model.getMessageText().contains(DATABASE_URL)) {
                messageText.setText("Image sent: ");
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(model.getMessageText()).into(img);
            }
            else {
                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            }

            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", (long)model.getMessageTime().get("timestamp")));
        }
    };
    listOfMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Chat is fully functional. However, when it comes to images, I have `DATABASE_URL` to determine that what's being received should be an image instead of text, so I load it in with Picasso as above:

```
 if (model.getMessageText().contains(DATABASE_URL)) {
                messageText.setText("Image sent: ");
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(model.getMessageText()).into(img);
            }
```

However, when it is normal text, my:

```
else {
     messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
}
```

Will show the text as normal, but still display an image - always the most recent image displayed. I have tried adding `img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` into the `else` statement, as well as equivalent removals from Glide/Picasso but they all end up in every single image being removed and not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because You are reusing one type of layout. Every view which will be showed next will reuse the previous one. If You don't invalidate layout's views, it can happen situation where one of the views will contain old data.

This layout is just like a skeleton where You pin some elements. Then someone want to reuse Your skeleton. He gets it with Your stuff. So he has to remove all elements and after that he can pin own stuff. If You bend something in the skeleton, next guy will have to unbend otherwise he will have skeleton with bended element (i.e. `setVisibility(INVISIBLE)->setVisibility(VISIBLE)`).

As soon as You get the layout, reset values in all views.

Comment: How would I go by resetting the values in all views when I get the layout?

Comment: Ok I did it. All I had to do was add `img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to the if statement.